# Why does .gitignore appear in git status?

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

I have some perl scripts that should be under `git` versioning. I run `ctags` against them to be able to jump to definitions so a `tags` file has been autogenerated in the directories. Now I want `git` to ignore these `tags` files so I created a `.gitignore` right next to the `.git` folder of my repository.
If I do `git status` I don't see `tags` but I see `.gitignore`.
Is `.gitignore` supposed to appear as an untracked change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.gitignore` file is a regular file from Git's perspective. It is normal to create and commit your `.gitignore` file early in the project as soon as you know what files should be ignored - There is a collation of lots of ignore files somewher on github to cover whatever languages you have in use.  In this can I presume you want this ignoring action to continue, so just commit the `.gitignore` file with a suitable message e.g. "Added .gitignore file", and carry on happily.

Comment: The ignore works based specifically on the file name, right?Not where a file is located correct?

Comment: Yes, and No. You can have .gitignore files all the way down providing special case processing on a per directory basis. Or you just have a the one all encompassing file at the top level. Try https://github.com/github/gitignore for those templates...